# Cannot reference html2pdf after npm install

Tags: ag-grid, html2pdf

I have just installed the html2pdf using npm.  I am running an Angular 2 project using an ag-Grid.

When I look at the node_modules folder in the project I can see html2pdf.

I then try to run html2pdf(this.element) where this.element is the id of an ag-Grid.

I get the error - Cannot find name 'html2pdf'.  Do I need to add a path or something?  Note that npm seemed to install html2pdf without a hitch.

Comment: Do you import that html2pdf to your component/module? Please provide all needed code parts so that people can see and help you.

Comment: Thank you ... I had forgotten to import ... DOH!  All working correctly now.

Comment: Rob Shepherd, you are welcome! I suggest next time to get a help from community you need to add specific tags to your question. The tags that you have in this particular question are not enough and do not state the main technology that you use. For example in my opinion this question should have `Angular` tag because this is the main technology that you are using for development and there are many people who follow this tag , thus the probability of getting help becomes bigger.